# Unknown plugin "transform-runtime" specified in "Users\\PhpstormProjects\\easy-essay\\.babelrc

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp, babeljs

I have download a github repository.

in the file called .babelrc.json, I have this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime",
    "add-module-exports",
    "transform-decorators-legacy"
  ]
}
```

When I run `gulp dev`,  I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-runtime" specified in
>   "C:\Users\Tolotra Samuel\PhpstormProjects\easy-essay\.babelrc" at
>   0, attempted to resolve relative to "C:\Users\ \Tolotra
>   Samuel\PhpstormProjects\easy-essay"
>       at C:\Users\Tolotra Samuel\PhpstormProjects\easy-essay\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:180:17
>       at Array.map (native)
>       at Function.normalisePlugins (C:\Users\Tolotra Samuel\PhpstormProjects\easy-essay\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:158:20)
>       at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\Users\Tolotra Samuel\PhpstormProjects\easy-essay\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:234:36)
>       at OptionManager.init (C:\Users\Tolotra Samuel\PhpstormProjects\easy-essay\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:368:12)
>       at compile (C:\Users\Tolotra Samuel\PhpstormProjects\easy-essay\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:103:45)
>       at loader (C:\Users\Tolotra Samuel\PhpstormProjects\easy-essay\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:14)
>       at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\Tolotra
>   Samuel\PhpstormProjects\easy-essay\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
>       at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)

As mentionned in the readme file, I already ran `npm install`  and `bower install`. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

```
yarn add babel-plugin-transform-runtime
```

solved for me, what about for you?

or npm or bower.
But don't forget to refer to babel-plugin mentioned above. Its a lib from babel. 
Looks like its a bug refered to install babel globally =)

prob you got an error refering to es2015 after so try this >

```
yarn add babel-plugin-transform-runtime babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-stage-2 --dev
```